# Pass string value to date in Unix

Tags: shell-script, quoting

```
mm="27 Jun 2011"
dd=$(date -d'27 Jun 2011' +%Y%m%d)
echo $dd
```

I want to use value of mm in second line. When i tried  like below

```
dd=$(date -d'$mm' +%Y%m%d)
```

It is giving error.

Comment: double quotes: `$(date -d"$mm" +%Y%m%d)`

Comment: see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/quoting/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
dd=$(date -d"$mm" +%Y%m%d)
```

That's all.

---

*Example*

```
% mm="27 Jun 2011"
% dd=$(date -d"$mm" +%Y%m%d)
% echo $dd
20110627
```

to compare with your version

```
% dd=$(date -d"27 Jun 2011" +%Y%m%d)
% echo $dd
20110627

% dd=$(date -d'27 Jun 2011' +%Y%m%d)
% echo $dd
20110627
```